# Updating and deleting values in a json object in Postgresql 14

Tags: json, postgresql-14

The table has a json field that stores data in the following form:

```
[{"9":[111,222]},{"11":[444,555]}]
```

I need to update the values of a json object.
For example, the values in the update parameters come in this form:

```
 param1 = 11;
 param2 = [444,666,777];
```

What is the best way to update a field to get data in this form?

```
[{"9":[111,222]},{"11":[444,666,777]}]
```

What is the best way to update a field to remove data from a json string when, for example, parameters with such values arrive?

```
param1 = 11;
param2 = [null];
```

Need to get

```
[{"9":[111,222]}]
```

Thanks